# Standardization Result is different between Patsy & Pandas - Python

Tags: python, pandas, data-processing, patsy, standardization

I found an interesting question and I would love to hear your interpretation.

```
from patsy import dmatrix,demo_data
df = pd.DataFrame(demo_data("a", "b", "x1", "x2", "y", "z column"))

Patsy_Standarlize_Output = dmatrix("standardize(x2) + 0",df).ravel()
output = (df['x2'] - df['x2'].mean()) / df['x2'].std()
Pandas_Standarlize_Output = output.ravel()
```

if you print out results for standardized **x2 columns**, you will find out the result is quite different. The result is as follow:

**Patsy_Standarlize_Output** = [-1.21701061, -0.07791372, -0.66884723,  2.23584028,  0.69898536, -0.71843674, -0.00416815, -0.2484492 ]

**Pandas_Standarlize_Output** = [-1.13840918, -0.07288161, -0.62564929,  2.09143707,  0.65384094, -0.67203603, -0.00389895, -0.23240294]

My question is since I conducted the standardization for the same column, Why the results are different?

I am looking forward to hear your great interpretation! and Thank you so much for your time and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pandas' `std()` performs [Bessel correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel%27s_correction), while most other libraries don't. It practically doesn't matter once you have several dozen points, but for small samples it is a very reasonable thing to do.

Proof: if you replace `df['x2'].std()` with numpy version (`df['x2'].values.std()`), the results will match

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explaination! It is really helpful!